# How can I generate a diamond-shaped gradient?

Tags: html, css, gradient, linear-gradients

My goal is to create the follwing pattern:

[image: diamond-shaped gradient]

Can I generate this kind of gradient using only vanilla CSS?

I've seen this done in figma. However, there's only `conic-gradient` in CSS and no specific diamond-gradient.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+star+shaped+gradient+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this effect by blending together two linear gradients, perpendicular to each other.

```css
.diamond {
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(to left, #000, #0f0, #000),
    linear-gradient(to top, #000, #0f0, #000);
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="diamond">Diamond gradient</div>
```